# Condition of periodic function for |sin πx|

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

Period of |sin πx| = 1

Wolfram alpha :

[image]

So why this condition for Periodic function is not true?

f(x) = f(x + T)

Wolfram alpha :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate

$$|\sin(\pi\cdot (0 + 1))|$$

and not

$$|\sin(\pi\cdot 0)+1|$$

Comment: I commit egregious error. Maybe because i'm newbie in math. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You should put it $|sin(\pi(0+1))|$ You should replace $x$ by $x+1$. Check their graphs for better understanding